# How to disable location service by chromedriver selenium?

Tags: service, selenium, location, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium 2 - Webdriver , Chromedriver, Java.  One of my tests needs to turn off the location service on Chrome .

I notice that by default, the location service is turned on Chromedriver.

I'm wondering if there is a way to disable location service on chromedriver?

many thanks in advance!

Comment: does anyone know if chromedriver supports disabling location service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.
Use the ChromeOptions class, in the following way:

```
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
 jsonObject.put("profile.default_content_settings.geolocation", 2);

 options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", jsonObject);
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

You can see it as an answer for an issue [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=138)

Comment: How would you do it if the chrome options were in hashmap form?
Map<String, Object> chromeOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();

Comment: @elrobe I would try to convert the relevant entry from the Map<String,Object> to ChromeOptions. Please note that ChromeOptions.setExperimentalOption receive String and Object argument, that's exactly what you have in your map. Just copy the values from your map to as setExperimentalOption arguments.

Comment: Just for a reference: JSONObject is created by this library [json-simple](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/).

Comment: SetExperimentalOption is not available in chromeoptions anymore I think AddAdditionalCapability() will work

Comment: or use the AddUserProfilePreference() method, which can be used instead using a jsonobject and can add the preferences directly to the method