# How to add allow site on location of chrome content setting with selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selendroid

I want to add site "a.com" on mobile chrome using selenium.
Option - [Advanced-content setting-location-ask before accessing-allow site]

Because i want to rid of the popup on my testing

[image]

Does anyone know?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable chrome asking for location you need to use `ChromeOptions` and disable `geolocation` from profile settings

```
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
 jsonObject.put("profile.default_content_settings.geolocation", 2);

 options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", jsonObject);
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Please see that the whole answer is already explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808310/how-to-disable-location-service-by-chromedriver-selenium) SO post.

Edit : In case, the option is to be kept enabled, you just need to change this line

```
jsonObject.put("profile.default_content_settings.geolocation", 2);
```

to

```
jsonObject.put("profile.default_content_settings.geolocation", 1);
```

Comment: OP's question is about `add allow site` :) but your code is disabling it. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for answer. can i ask one more? "prefs" is only working on DeskTop Chrome. How do i have to do on Mobile Chrome?

Comment: @DebanjanB OP's talks about `rid of the popup on my testing` which leads me to believe he wants to ignore/disable this.

Comment: @LeBronPark you can use Mobile Emulation to achieve this. [Here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/mobile-emulation) is a link for same.

Comment: @demouser123 You are right (+1) Can you help me to set it `Allow` (always)? Thanks

Comment: does work? this code doesn't work on chrome of android. 

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1015&can=1&q=prefs%20android&colspec=ID%20Status%20Pri%20Owner%20Summary

Answer (score 1):

Use chrome devtools protocol can do this.[Browser.grantPermission](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Browser#method-grantPermissions) allow to config the geolocation permission before accessing the target website. You can look at my another answer for more detail [Setting sensors (location) in headless Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60473486/7035932)
.

Answer (score 0):

The below code snippet working for me to disable that pop up. Instead of `profile.default_content_settings.geolocation`,

I used `profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications`.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 1);

options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", jsonObject);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

or

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 1);

options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```