# Setting sensors (location) in headless Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, gps, sensors, headless

Is it possible to set custom location coordinates with Chrome Headless? I can't find it in the 
[Devtools protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/)
API. Is there a workaround available?

Answer (score 4):

I googled it and got many methods. I try one by one, almost all of them turn out outdated. Then I find out a solution, use chrome devtools protocol to achieve that.

The small example code below, that it uses the most common tool selenium to execute chrome devtools protocol command.

```py
import time

from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = Chrome(options=options)
driver.execute_cdp_cmd(
    "Browser.grantPermissions",
    {
        "origin": "https://www.openstreetmap.org/",
        "permissions": ["geolocation"]
    },
)
driver.execute_cdp_cmd(
    "Emulation.setGeolocationOverride",
    {
        "latitude": 35.689487,
        "longitude": 139.691706,
        "accuracy": 100,
    },
)
driver.get("https://www.openstreetmap.org/")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='icon geolocate']").click()
time.sleep(3)  # wait for the page full loaded
driver.get_screenshot_as_file("screenshot.png")
```

[image: screenshot.png]

Comment: So many half-answers to this question on the web, but this answer actually works. Huge thank you.

Answer (score 0):

https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Emulation#method-setGeolocationOverride

and

https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Emulation#method-clearGeolocationOverride

... then you'll need to contend with ensuring that the correct location sharing setting is set within the user profile (chrome://settings/content/location - which is difficult to access due to being displayed via shadow dom, so using a preconfigured user profile will likely be easier `--user-data-dir`).

Edit to add: The above does not seem to be effective when using `--headless`. To resolve this I used https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page#method-addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument with the following snippet:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition = function(success, failure) { 
    success({
        coords: {latitude: <your_lat_float>, longitude: <your_lng_float>}, 
        timestamp: Date.now(),
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Hey there, how do you implement that?